# Template class override base class virtual function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, overriding, virtual

Consider the following code:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void* allocate(){ return nullptr; }
};

template <class T> class BaseTemplate : public Base
{
public:
    void* allocate() override { return new T(); }
};

class IntSpecialization : public BaseTemplate<int>
{
};

Base GetSpecialization(const int&){ return IntSpecialization(); }
```

The goal is to be able to use template to implement specializations, but still allow users to work using the base class interface, such as:

```
int a;
auto s = GetSpecialization(a);
auto p = s.allocate();
```

The above code does not work; `s.allocate()` always return `nullptr` for obvious reasons.

I absolutely need the `GetSpecialization` function to return the `Base` non-template class, so how do I go about this?

The `Base` class virtual method cannot be pure, because otherwise it becomes abstract and it will fail the compilation at `GetSpecialization`.

What is the best approach to solve this pattern? Using C++11?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Base GetSpecialization(const int&){ return IntSpecialization(); }
```

You're [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c) the `IntSpecialization` object above. To make your code work, `GetSpecialization` must return a `Base *`, or a `Base&`. For instance, the following will work as you intended it to:

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> GetSpecialization(const int&)
{ 
    return std::unique_ptr<Base>(new IntSpecialization()); 
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7132fe18a29ea73f)

For the above code to work, you'll need to add a `virtual` destructor to `Base`.

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void* allocate(){ return nullptr; }
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};
```

Otherwise, when the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope it'll call `delete ptr;`, where the type of `ptr` is `Base *`, and polymorphic deletion of a derived class object through a base class pointer is undefined behavior unless the base class destructor is `virtual`.

Comment: Could you also do `return {new IntSpecialization()}`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 The `unique_ptr(T*)` constructor is `explicit`, so copy-list-initialization will fail.

Comment: @T.C. Because his `Base` doesn't have a `virtual` destructor. I should add that to the answer.

Comment: @Praetorian Good point, but your code then move-constructs that into a `std::unique_ptr<Base>`...doesn't that defeat the purpose?

Comment: @T.C. I was just playing around with that to see if it actually worked. I assumed that since I'm constructing a `unique_ptr<Base>` from a `unique_ptr<Derived>`, the former would copy/move the deleter and use `default_delete<Derived>` to delete the object, but it [looks like](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c57354968840b45d) I was wrong. Time to update the answer again.

Comment: @T.C. So `default_delete` has a copy constructor that is a template. That's why it didn't work the way I was expecting it to, and now it seems obvious why this is necessary. So the only way to get around a base class not having a virtual destructor would be to use a custom deleter that performs the necessary cast to derived pointer before deleting.

Answer (score 0):

Just make Base have pointer to BaseTemplate:

```
class BaseInterface {
public:
    virtual void* allocate() = 0;
}

class Base
{
   std::unique_ptr<BaseInterface> interface;
public:
    Base( BaseInterface *i ) : interface( i ) {}
    void* allocate(){ return interface->allocate(); }
};

template <class T> class BaseTemplate : public BaseInterface
{
public:
    void* allocate() override { return new T(); }
};

class IntSpecialization : public BaseTemplate<int>
{
};

Base GetSpecialization(const int&){ return Base( new IntSpecialization ); }
```

Less verbose solution is to use `std::function` and lambda

```
class Base 
{
public:
    typedef std::function<void *()> creator;
    Base( const creator &c ) : cr( c ) {}
    void *allocate() { return cr(); }
private:
    creator cr;
};

template<class T>
Base GetSpecialization( const T & ) { return Base( []() { return new T; } ); }
```